# Carrier name in the status bar not showing

Tags: ios, cellular-carriers

I noticed my phone not displaying my carrier name (Vodafone UK) in the status bar at the top of the screen, but then after a few minutes it came back (I’m running iOS 12.3.1). Does anyone know what happened?

[image: Screenshots of the status bar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From searching around the internet I found a few users were experiencing this bug on iOS 12. If it comes back, you can update to iOS 13 and that should fix it.

You can also [Update Your Carrier Settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201270):

> 1. Make sure your device is connected to a Wi-Fi or cellular network.
> 2. Tap Settings > General > About. If an update is available, you'll see an option to update your carrier settings.

It could also be an issue with your carrier.

Comment: Could you link where you found reports of other users experiencing this?

Comment: @DM01131 to link a few: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250309914 https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/9l5uk1/ios_12_not_showing_carrier_name_bug/

Comment: Thanks @Daniil, the reddit thread looks more like what I was experiencing. It’s very weird though as I have had iOS 12 for a long time and have not experienced this before.

Comment: This problem happened to me. No "Update Your Carrier Settings" could be found but a general iOS software was available. Did it, now carrier displays.